Why after changing the Recovery Model to Full it is not reflected?
Good day,
I could not find the answer in any place. It would be great if someone of you had the same experience and solved it.
The SQL Version is
Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP3-CU1-GDR) (KB5040944) - 13.0.7037.1 (X64)
Jun 19 2024 14:36:41
Due some experiments in backups, I changed the recovery Model (in a user database) to FULL by Alter DATABASE statement and later also in SSMS.
I performed the FULL and DIFFERENTIAL Backups with success and
when I tried the Log Backup
"The statement BACKUP LOG is not allowed while the recovery model is SIMPLE."
In SSMS interface the Recovery Model if showed as "Full"
However, in the system view sys.databases is still recognized as SIMPLE.
There are no other activities in charge to apply, directly or indirectly, the change of recovery model.
The SQL Server Logs shows properly the changes I have applied (Last one to FULL) and not any reversion. I don't believe it is required the restart of the Service for a similar change.
Any suggestion would be really appreciated.
Thank you
Martin

Update 2024-08-21 06:05 (UTC)
This behavior is not happening on another instance with version
Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP3-CU1-GDR) (KB5029187) - 13.0.7029.3 (X64)
Aug 16 2023 19:44:44

If you restart SSMS, does it still show simple mode for the DB in the GUI?

Hi @vonPryz,
Thank you for your comment. I had totally missed this test.
After the SSMS restart everything seems back to normal.
So, the only explanation I am thinking is the issue resides on client side (cache .Net objects used by SSMS)
and not on the server side.
By the way, the SSMS Version I used is 19.0.2
Please, feel free to post your answer and I can give the mark.
Thank you very much again!
Martin
